# How to create report in the format Like this?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have been searching on the web for a while but couldn't find a solution.

I want to use *JasperReports* for a format like this:

```
--------------------------
Name:
Address:
Phone #
-------------------------
Domain       Total   Price 
www.a.com      100    7500
www.b.com      150    1500
--------------------------
Type         Total   Price
Hosting        350    3500
Surfing        175    2200
--------------------------
```

It's just like if I need multiple *Detail* bands, I can create multiple *Detail* bands but the problem what I have is, I want to show the Column Titles only once, so in the case of (Domain, Total, Price) I can do it by placing them in the *Column Header* band but I can not find any luck for the other *Detail* band (Type, Total, Price)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**: The dataset is presented in this way:

```
 Type    Domain    Total   Count 
 null    www.a.com 200     30 
 null    www.b.com 100     95 
 Hosting null      300     65 
 Surfing null      100     25
```

Comment: so what  have you tried till time

Comment: please post a mock up of your query.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for being responsive.
@Satya : I have tried to do with sub reports, but that is not gonna work as the main issue is I want the two column headers somehow, all other things are pretty much fine...

So, being more precise, I just want the two column headers somehow, and these two column headers must not repeat themselves like the Details band do....
So please if that helps, if you have any further questions, please ask me.

Thanks
Mr.777

Comment: @MrsTang : I am actually passing the Datasource from my Java code. So, the report has everything it wants....

So, being more precise, I just want the two column headers somehow, and these two column headers must not repeat themselves like the Details band do....
So please if that helps, if you have any further questions, please ask me.

Thanks
Mr.777

Comment: Will the report always be for a single Name/Address/Phone or can there be multiple Names?

Comment: Name, Address, Phone will always be single because they are in the Page Header band.
What I care for is the Column Header and Details band..

I just want somehow to get the functionality like this:

Column Header1
Detail1 Band
Column Header2
Detail2 Band

Thanks...
Mr.777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the structure of the dataset as posted in the comment:

- create a report group based on this expression `$F{domain} == null ? "Type" : "Domain"`
- in the group header add a text field with expression `$F{domain} == null ? "Type" : "Domain"` and 2 static texts for *Total* and *Price*.
- in the detail band add these text fields with expressions:

  - field 1: `$F{domain}==null ? $F{type} :$F{domain}`
  - field 2: `$F{total}`
  - field 3: `$F{count} * $F{total}`
- in group footer add the line

Done.

Assuming that there are 2 results sets:

- add for each results set a sub dataset (i.e. `datasetDomains`, `datesetTypes`)
- add a (*fake*) report group (i.e. with group expression `null`)
- add in the group header 3 *static text* fields containing *Domain*, *Total*, *Price*
- add below these fields a *List* item containing the fields of `datasetDomains`.
- add below the list a line, configure it with *Position Type* `Fix Relative To Bottom`.
- add in the group footer 3 *static text* fields containing *Type*, *Total*, *Price*
- add below these fields a *List* item containing the fields of `datesetTypes`.
- add below the list a line, configure it with *Position Type* `Fix Relative To Bottom`.

[image]

If your resultset was structured like the following, things would be easiest:

```
Type     Detail         Total  Price
----     ------         -----  -----
Domain   www.a.com      100    7500
Domain   www.b.com      150    1500
Type     Hosting        350    3500
Type     Surfing        175    2200
```

you can do the following:

- create a group based on `type`
- use the group header band for labels (instead of column header band).

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer @MrsTang but I have only one dataset and that is like;

Type,       Domain,       Total, Count
null        www.a.com     200     30
null        www.b.com     100     95
Hosting     null          300     65
Surfing     null          100     25

So, any help with this one?

Thanks
Mr.777

Comment: i modified the question and answer to reflect the details given in your comment.

Comment: Sure thing, I will give this one a try tonight and will ask questions if I had, otherwise will mark it Solved.

Thanks a lot.